# Enquote multiple text fields in CSV - Sublime Text 3

Tags: sql, csv, sublimetext3, regexp-replace

I have a CSV file containing info to be inserted in a database with SQL using insert similar to the below example:

```
INSERT INTO `Person`(`name`, `occupation`, `residence`, `comments`) VALUES
(GIBEL ΕΛΛΗ,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

I want to separate the text values from the null values. Specifically, I want to enquote text values and leave null as it is. Is there a way to do this using Sublime Text 3? Please bear in mind that I am not familiar with regexp. Each field in my DB is either VARCHAR or TEXT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example you supplied

```
INSERT INTO `Person`(`name`, `occupation`, `residence`, `comments`) VALUES (GIBEL ΕΛΛΗ,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

**Activate RegEx** in ST3 Find and Replace.

Find Value

```
(.*VALUES \()(.*)(,NULL,NULL,NULL\))
```

Replace Value

```
$1"$2"$3
```

Apply **Replace All**

Result

```
INSERT INTO `Person`(`name`, `occupation`, `residence`, `comments`) VALUES ("GIBEL ΕΛΛΗ",NULL,NULL,NULL)
```